How to Copy Messages from Forum Topics to Users Using Telegram API?
I'm working on a messaging system where I need to copy messages from forum topics to users using the Telegram API. According to the official Telegram documentation, in CopyMessage request there's only one message_thread_id key, which seems to be working only for copying messages from users to forum topics, not the other way around. How can I use the Telegram API to copy messages from forum topics to users, given that the message_thread_id key seems to work only for user-to-topic messages? Any help or insights into this would be greatly appreciated.
Here's a sample JSON request for copying a message:
{
  "chat_id": 1106660938,
  "message_thread_id": 2,
  "from_chat_id": "-1002213908537",
  "message_id": 32
}

In this structure:

chat_id is the ID of the destination chat (user or topic).
message_thread_id is used to specify the thread in a forum.
from_chat_id is the ID of the original chat.
message_id is the ID of the message to be copied.

this request(if all data is correct) result in 400 stating: Bad Request: message thread not found
Additional Information:

I'm making direct API requests to Telegram.
The current structure assumes a unidirectional message flow from users to forum topics.

Thank you in advance for your help!

"from_chat_id is the ID of the original chat" - and that is actually supposed to be a negative number ...?

Don't quite understand your question. Sure your bot can access those chats / forums?

@0stone0 it definitely can, in Copy Message request you send id of chat where you want to copy it from, message id in that chat, id of chat you want to send it to and optionally id of topic in supergroup. My confusion came from not realising that ids are global in supergroup, so if you send message to topic a and then to topic b, id of second message will be id of message sent in topic a + 1. This way if you want to send message from forum topic you dont need to specify id of topic in supergroup that it came from

@CBroe yes, in telegram api to differentiate group ids from user ids (here chat id can be both user is and group id) when referring to group ids it will be always negative numbers

Actually, you don't have to specify the message_thread_id if you are copying the message to a private chat.
The from_chat_id and the message_id can be together used to uniquely identify the message inside the Forum topic.
So you just need to call the copyMessage method with these parameters:
{
  "chat_id": 1106660938,
  "from_chat_id": -1002213908537,
  "message_id": 32
}

Why did I get that error?
It's because private chats don't have threads. The message_thread_id is considered only for the destination chat. Since, the destination chat (specified with the chat_id) is of a user's private chat with the bot it do not have threads. Hence, raising the error:
400: Bad Request: message thread not found

Hope this helps :)
